# (0-1) knapsack polytope

Tags: discrete-mathematics, discrete-optimization, binary-programming

$$P = \{x \in \{0,1\}^4 : 4x_1 + 3x_2 + 2x_3 + x_4 \leq 4\}$$

I have to disaggregate the main constraint in $P$ by using minimal cover extension procedure.
I have found that minimal cover is: $\{2,3,4\}$, $\{1, 2\}$, $\{1,3\}$, $\{1,4\}$?
I'm not sure if I'm correct so far, please help!

Answer (score 1):

You want to find minimal solutions that satisfy $4x_1 + 3x_2 + 2x_3 + x_4 > 4$.  Your last three are correct, but $\{2,3,4\}$ is not minimal.

Comment: oh sorry for mistake, it is less <=4

Comment: can you please explain why ?

Comment: It is a cover, but a proper subset is also a cover.

Comment: So minimal cover would be: {1,2}, {1,3},{1,4},{2,4},{2,3}?

Comment: $\{2,4\}$ is not a cover.  The others are the minimal covers.

Comment: Okay so there are only those 4 minimal covers, right?

Comment: Yes, there are no others.

Comment: So if i try to extend my minimal cover do I get: {1,2,4} and {1,2 3} ?